# Не импортируется библиотека OpenCV

Tags: linux, python-3.x, opencv

Пытаюсь настроить захват изображения с вебкамеры, использую `opencv-python 4.1.0.25` (сам работаю с `python 3.6` на Ubuntu 17.04), но выходит ошибка:

```
python3 pseudo.py
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pseudo.py", line 43, in <module>
import cv2
File "/home/maxwell/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

А вот код самого файла:

```
import cv2 as cv
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
cv.SaveImage("capture.jpg", frame)
```

Хотелось бы понять, в чём дело - что надо перенастроить, изменить или от чего избавиться?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте обновить `numpy`.

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

Comment: ругается на эту команду и выдаёт `SyntaxError`
Но я и до этого пытался решить проблема со стороны numpy и несколько раз переустанавливал её

Comment: Это не команда python. Это команда системы. Вы пользуетесь `venv`, `anaconda`, или только системные пакеты (`apt`)?

Comment: прошу прощения, не заметил, что забыл выйти из python3, сейчас ещё раз попробую

Comment: Обновил, но терминал продолжает ругаться

Comment: До какой версии обновили? Каким способом? На что и как ругается "терминал"? Вы пользуетесь `venv`, `anaconda`, или только системные пакеты (`apt`)?